# ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Having problem with ActionView then when i check at apache error.log it says:

```
App 7703 stdout:
App 7703 stdout: ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
App 7703 stdout:     23:     <div class="content">
App 7703 stdout:     24:     <div class="container-fluid">
App 7703 stdout:     25:
App 7703 stdout:     26:        <%= yield %>
App 7703 stdout:     27:
App 7703 stdout:     28:     </div>
App 7703 stdout:     29: </body>
App 7703 stdout:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:26:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3122313295899581692_128215760'
App 7703 stdout:
```

Answer (score 0):

Open "**application.html.erb**" in **Git Gui**. All incompatible characters you will catch immediatelly Æ